# Getting subsets of signatures in Alloy

Tags: subset, modeling, alloy, requirements

I was wondering if there is a way to extract a subset of a set in a given signature in Alloy.
The extracted set will then be used in the definition of some facts of the model.

Assume the following model:

```
abstract sig Status{}
one sig Status1 extends Status{}
one sig Status2 extends Status{}

sig A {
     status: one Status
}

sig B {
     setA: set A
}

fun SubsetOfSetAinB [b: B] : set A {
    //have some kind of operation here 
    //that returns a subset of b.setA where b.setA.status in Status1
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this with a set intersection, like `b.setA & Status1.~status`.

Comment: that solution is the most optimal

Answer (score 1):

You already gave the answer yourself :-). You only lacked 5 characters:

```
fun SubsetOfSetAinB [b: B] : set A {
    { x : b.setA | b.setA.status in Status1 }
}
```

The enumeration with `{ vars | test(vars) }`  is incredibly useful for lots of problems.